# How to clone/copy MongoDB database from remote server to local?

Tags: mongodb

I am having trouble to copy database to my local computer from remote server.

I use ssh to work on the remote machine. Database is not password protected. I tried to run on my local computer:

```
> db.copyDatabase('DatabaseName', 'CopyName', 'ns35512048.ip-31-127-173.eu', 'root', 'server password');
```

and I get

```
{
"ok" : 0,
"errmsg" : "couldn't connect to server ns35512048.ip-31-127-173.eu:27017 (31-127-173.133), connection attempt failed"
```

}

Can you please help :)

EDIT:
I ended up copying database manually.

Comment: You can create ssh tunnel to the remote server and use copy only between ports in the localhost

Answer (score 0):

You have firewall what blocks that connection. 
As another user wrote, tunneling connection is one solution.. 
Or you could dump data out on source and import it to your local machine..